# When is 'this' captured in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a function in a class that defines a lambda and stores it in a local static variable:

```
class A
{
public:
    void call_print()
    {
        static auto const print_func = [this] {
            print();
        };

        print_func();
    };

    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout << "A::print()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "B::print()\n";
    }
};
```

I also execute the following test:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.call_print();
    b.call_print();
}
```

([Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe9b4702bb01d02))

What I expect to be printed is:

```
A::print()
B::print()
```

But what I really get is:

```
A::print()
A::print()
```

(Same object address is also printed with each)

I suspect this is due to the `this` capture. I assumed that it would capture the value of `this` when it is called, however it seems to be captured the moment the lambda is defined.

Could someone explain the semantics of lambda captures? When do they actually get provided to the function? Is it the same for all capture types, or is `this` a special case? Removing `static` fixes the problem, however in my production code I'm actually storing the lambda in a slightly-heavier object which represents a slot to which I insert into a signal later.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the semantics of lambda capture. It's simply how `static` works.

A `static` function-scoped variable is initialized *exactly once*. There is only ever one such object in your entire program. It will be initialized the first time the function is called (more specifically, the first time the `static` statement is executed). And therefore, the expression used to initialize the `static` variable is only ever invoked once.

So if a `static` function-scoped variable is initialized with data that's based on one of the function's parameters (like `this`), then it will only get the parameters from the first invocation of that function.

Your code creates a single lambda. It does not create different lambdas on each invocation of the function.

The behavior you seem to want is not a function-local `static` variable, but an object member. So just put a `std::function` object in the class itself, and have `call_print` initialize it if it is empty.

Comment: It might be worth adding that this actually represents a very dangerous programming style, since if `a` gets deleted, future calls to `call_print` will invoke undefined behavior and very likely crash.

Comment: @Xirema That's very true, but I don't think that this is the behavior he's trying to get.

Comment: I understand the semantics of `static`, what I am trying to figure out is if the lambda "promises" to capture `this` *later*, or if it's captured *right then*. You did address this in your response, though. I wanted the container for the lambda to be static, but not the captures. I was hoping they were separated between definition & invocation.

Comment: @void.pointer, captures are captured at the point of the lambda definition, so it's *right then*

Comment: @void.pointer: How could a lambda capture *anything* at some point after its generation? Lambdas aren't magic; they're just a fancy way of declaring types.

Comment: @void.pointer _"I wanted the container for the lambda to be static, but not the captures."_ That would be like `struct S { int i; }; static const S s { 42 };` and expect `s.i` to be different every time.

Comment: I realize what I'm asking doesn't make sense in the context of reference and by-value captures, I guess I for some reason was thinking `this` capture would be a special case. But seeing as how the invocation can actually occur outside of the class itself, it's not possible to capture `this` later. Thanks for clarifying with examples.

Comment: @void.pointer You may not understand the semantics of `static` as well as you think if you thought that *anything* in the expression that initializes the static value would be evaluated multiple times or in different ways (the fact that it's a lambda is pretty much irrelevant). Also, the scope of the invocation has nothing to do with anything; as other commenters have pointed out, captures *always* happen *when the lambda is initialized*. This is **the entire point of a "capture".**. It is what "capture" **means**.

Comment: @void.pointer: I think the condescension comes from thinking about your question. It is ***impossible*** for C++ to define that `this` is captured at the site of the first call, because that site may not be inside of where `this` came from (just like any other capture). If you pass a `this`-capturing-lambda to `std::sort`, how could `this` penetrate that function call and get captured inside of `sort`? From that perspective, your question could be rephrased as, "Do lambdas do something that is fundamentally impossible?"

Comment: @void.pointer:  That's why everyone assumed that your problem was understanding the behavior of `static`. Because there's no way that lambdas could ever magically capture the way you seemed to think they were.

Comment: @NicolBolas "I think the condescension comes from thinking about your question" -- yes, that's it exactly, plus the fact that OP continued to express confusion while insisting that they understand the issue. Nevertheless, I did not *intend* to come across as condescending or insulting, though I can see now that that's precisely how I came across.

Comment: @void.pointer I apologize for the phrasing of my first comment, in particular "you may not understand...as well as you think." The point remains, however, that I am concerned that you really are revealing your "unknown unknowns" in this discussion: that is, the way you are talking about `static` and captures still does not seem to indicate that you've absorbed the explanations above. I don't mean this to be insulting: again, SO is for explaining these types of technical concepts, and uncovering and addressing misunderstandings is a large part of this.

Comment: Maybe the minds here are not simple enough to take my question with a grain of salt. It feels like everyone is over-analyzing my questions and proposing a lot of "would-have-should-have" scenarios. Hindsight is 20/20. I just got confused. Great answers here have help to put my mind back on track, and other than feeling a little silly about my question now, I walk away with the answers I need. If I knew all the problems with my question ahead of time I wouldn't have asked it or been confused in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

The lambda is instantiated the first time the enclosing function `A::call_print()` is called. Since the first time you call it on an `A` object, the `this` of that object is captured. If you reversed the order of invocation, you'd see a different result:

```
b.call_print();
a.call_print();
```

Output:

```
B::print()
B::print()
```

It more to do with the semantics of initialization of function-local static objects than those of lambda capture.

Answer (score 8):

Static local variables are initialized the first time their declaration is executed.

In this case, you:

1. Create a lambda, capturing &A as this, that calls A.print();
2. Assign that lambda to `print_func`
3. Call that lambda (through `print_func`)
4. Call that lambda again.

Captured values are always captured when the lambda is created - which in this case is during the first call to `call_print`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the capture is the problem here but the `static` keyword.
Think about your code as this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void call_print()
    {
        static A* ptr = this;

        ptr->print();
    };

    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout << "A::print()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "B::print()\n";
    }
};
```

This is pretty much the same without a lambda.

If you look at the code it becomes pretty clear that your call `a.call_print();` initializes `ptr` with a pointer to the object `a` which is then used further on.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not so much about the behaviour of lambdas, but about the behaviour of static variables in functions.

The variable is created the first time code flows over it, using whatever variables are available at that time.

example:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int v)
{
  static int value = v;
  return v;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << foo(10) << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo(11) << std::endl;
}
```

expected:

```
10
10
```

Because it's equivalent to:

```
foo::value = 10;
std::cout << foo::value << std::endl;
// foo::value = 11; (does not happen)
std::cout << foo::value << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the value of the capture is set when the lambda is defined, not when its called. Because you're setting a static variable to the expression that defines the lambda, this only happens the very first time the function `call_print` is called (by the rules governing static variables). Thus all `call_print` calls thereafter in fact get the same lambda, the one whose `this` is set to `&a`.